# Proving that JSD is symmetric?

Tags: self-study, kullback-leibler, divergence

How can I prove that the Jensen–Shannon divergence

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence)

is symmetric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straightforward: $$\begin{align}\text{JSD}(P||Q)&=\frac{1}{2}\text D(P||M)+\frac{1}{2}\text D(Q||M)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\text D(Q||M)+\frac{1}{2}\text D(P||M)\\&=\text{JSD}(Q||P)\end{align}$$

where $M=\frac{P+Q}{2}$, but it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: Addition is commutative, indeed!